# Java - Sorting a String array by word length

Tags: java, arrays

I need to sort the String array into least to greatest order by wordlength. I then need to print out the words next to their value.

Example Output:

1: I, U, K

6: Joseph, Delete

But I need help sorting the array first.

Code:

```
package Objects;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Object;

public class WordLength {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("wordlength.dat"));
    int thresh = scan.nextInt();   //Scans the first integer
    String[] array = new String[thresh];   //Creates an empty array with length of the threshold 

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = scan.nextLine();

        /* I need to sort the array from least to
        greatest here so I can use the if statement
        below.
        */

        //Prints the word array from least to greatest by length
        if(array[i].length() == i) {
            System.out.print(i + ": " + array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use Java Comparator for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom comparator to sort the `String` array. For example

```
        String [] arrr = {"World","Ho","ABCD"};
        Arrays.sort(arrr,new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.length() - o2.length();
            }
        });
        System.out.println(arrr[0]); \\ Output Ho
```

Answer (score 0):

One of [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) overloads accepts [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) as the second parameter, in which you can implement your own custom comparison function to determine whether a string should be placed before or after another simply by implementing the [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method.

Answer (score -1):

I don't code in Java, but would this pseudocode work?

```
Grab the list of words.
Loop through them.
   Get the length of the current word.
   Add that word to that array number:  a 5-letter word would go in array element 5.
Continue the loop until all the words have been added to the proper array.
Display each of the array elements.
```

Comment: Downvoter, this works in other languages. What's the problem with Java?